# Safely perform changes to NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

What can cause an assignment or change to an `NSMutableArray` to crash?
I have a mutable array containing custom objects, and I consistently keep no more than the 3 latest objects in it, the rest are removed. I started calling

```
[myArray insertObject:newObject atIndex:0];

if (myArray.count > 3)
    [myArray removeLastObject]; // Crash
```

But whenever I do this too fast, the last line causes an exception-less crash.
I know that you are not allowed to add or remove objects of an array while it is being enumerated, but I do not enumerate `myArray` anywhere unless calling `count` on it performs an implicit enumeration. I also tried doing this:

```
NSMutableArray *tmp = [myArray mutableCopy];
[tmp removeLastObject];
myArray = tmp; // Crash
```

But the same thing happens, it crashes on the last line. Again, this works perfectly fine when doing it slowly. The action itself is being called when a user taps a button, and when tapping it too fast, it crashes every time.

**EDIT:**

I should add that all of this is being run inside the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method of a `UICollectionView`.

Comment: Are you threading? What information exactly are you given when the application exits — what exception has been raised?

Comment: Why would you be manipulating an array *inside* `cellForItemAtIndexPath` ?  This method should simply return a cell

Comment: I am not threading, no. @Paulw11 I am using an MVP pattern, and I inject two views and presenters into each cell. Even though it's a quiet ugly solution, keeping the view controllers for the currently active cell and the next and previous ones in an array prevents the presenters from becoming deallocated, since no reference to them will exist otherwise. Each presenter belongs to a view controller.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you are trying to achieve, but you should probably associate your presenter with an element from your model using something like a dictionary rather than an arbitrary array.  You cannot rely on `cellForItemAtIndexPath` being called in a consistent order

Comment: @Paulw11 I will try using a dictionary, thank you. I realize that my situation is peculiar and that cellForItemAtIndexPath can indeed be called in an inconsistent order. I am still curious as to why the crashes happen. Wherever and however it gets called, I still do not understand how removeLastObject can fail when I just verified that it has a length of 4.

Comment: My guess is that you have a concurrency issue

Comment: I think @Paulw11 is correct. Perhaps in block
`if (myArray.count > 3)
    [myArray removeLastObject]; // Crash`
2 thread is call in the same time, so removeLastObject of last object is same address. In 1st thread it was deleted and the 2nd the address of last object is nil so it will be crashed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, could you please post the crash message. It would be nice to know what error you are actually seeing.

---

I wonder what would happen if you switched to immutable arrays. Switch `myArray` to being an `NSArray *` and use the following.

```
myArray = [self updatedArray:myArray withObject:newObject];
```

Where `-updatedArray:withObject:` is

```
- (NSArray *)updatedArray:(NSArray *)array withObject:(id)object {
    switch (array.count) {
    case 0: return @[object];
    case 1: return @[object, array[0]];
    default: return @[object, array[0], array[1]];
    }
}
```

Or better for testing

```
NSArray *temp = [self updatedArray:myArray withObject:newObject];
myArray = temp; // I assume the crash will be here!
```

If the code crashed at my comment, then deallocating `myArray` is causing the crash. My guess is that one of the items in the array is pointing to bad memory (a zombie or some such thing).

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two possible reasons for the crash:

1) The array is being accessed/mutated from multiple threads
2) An object inside the array was over-released somewhere, causing it to be deallocated while still living inside the array.

Short answer: try profiling your app in Instruments, and select the "Zombies" instrument. When the crash happens, you just might get a zombie alert, in which case you can get a back-log of everything that led up to your memory getting stomped over.

Answer (score 0):

I think the root cause is this variable is accessed from multiple threads at the same time.

You can use this when access the array

```
@synchronized(self) {
    //Your accessed code here
}
```